# "No FileSystem for scheme: s3" when importing data from postgres to s3 using sqoop

Tags: amazon-s3, sqoop

I tried to import data from local postgres to s3 using sqoop. My command is

````
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres --username username --password password --table table --driver org.postgresql.Driver --target-dir s3://xxxxxxxx/data/  -m 1```
````

I was able to import to a local directory, but failed for a s3 bucket.

The log is posted as below.

```
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/bin/../../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/bin/../../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
17/05/25 23:39:50 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/05/25 23:39:50 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/05/25 23:39:51 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
17/05/25 23:39:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/05/25 23:39:51 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/05/25 23:39:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM table AS t WHERE 1=0
17/05/25 23:39:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM table AS t WHERE 1=0
17/05/25 23:39:51 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local
Note: /tmp/sqoop-user/compile/faa4eb1b79a8e71f5c732c605f8968d8/table.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/05/25 23:40:00 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-user/compile/faa4eb1b79a8e71f5c732c605f8968d8/table.jar
17/05/25 23:40:00 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of table
17/05/25 23:40:00 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
17/05/25 23:40:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/25 23:40:01 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/05/25 23:40:01 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM table AS t WHERE 1=0
17/05/25 23:40:01 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:164)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.configureOutputFormat(ImportJobBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:259)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:160)
    ... 11 more
```

Really not sure how to add details to the log, or how to make log not look like code so it will not ask for more details. sorry.